# Router issue with m.route.link

Tags: mithril.js

While playing around with Mithril I stumbled upon this issue and I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature or I'm doing something wrong.

Please, run the script below and click on `View Two` and then on `Link three`. You'll see that the console outputs "RENDER TWO" each time you click on `Link three`. It doesn't make any sense, because in the code `link` component has neither `href` nor `oncreate: m.route.link` specified. It's as if it inherits it from the previous route or something. Also, if I remove `onclick` handler everything works as expected(console outputs nothing).

I've also opened an issue on github. If you feel you can help fix it please go [here](https://github.com/MithrilJS/mithril.js/issues/1854).

Anyway, do you have any idea what's going on?

```js
const outlet = document.body;

//COMPONENTS
class Link {
  view(vnode){
    return m('a', vnode.attrs, vnode.attrs.title);
  }
}
class ViewOne {
  view(vnode){
    return m('div', 'view one');
  } 
}
class ViewTwo {
  view(vnode){
    return m('div', this.getLinkThree());
  } 
  getLinkThree(){
    return m(Link, {
      title: 'Link three',
      onclick: () => {} // removing this handler solves the problem (routerResolver's render not invoked)
    });
  }
}

//HELPERS
const getLinkOne = () => {
  return m(Link, {
    title: 'View One',
    href: '/one',
    oncreate: m.route.link
  });
}
const getLinkTwo = () => {
  return m(Link, {
    title: 'View Two',
    href: '/two',
    oncreate: m.route.link
  });
}
const getViewHolder = () => {
  return m('#view-holder');
}

//INIT
m.render(outlet, [
  getLinkOne(), 
  getLinkTwo(),
  getViewHolder()
])
m.route(document.getElementById('view-holder'), "/one", {
  "/one": {
    render: () => {
      console.log('RENDER ONE');
      return m(ViewOne);
    }
  },
  "/two": {
    render: () => {
      console.log('RENDER TWO'); //also logs when clicking on 'Link three'
      return m(ViewTwo);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#view-holder {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mithril/1.1.1/mithril.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eugene, this is expected Mithril 1.x behavior: triggering a ui-event handler causes a vdom build + diff.

Separately it's ... unusual ... to have both `m.render()` and `m.route()` calls as part of setup. In this case just `m.route()` suffices. Pls see here (you'll need to prefix the following short-link with "https://"): goo.gl/z8rZFf

BTW the above leads to an editor called "Flems" -- it encodes file references, in-situ code, etc into the URL, so to share a Flems just copy/paste its URL. This has the advantage of being able to share work without creating physical resources such as w/ JSBin, etc, but a downside is that in most cases the URL needs to be shortened to be share-able.